# how to simplify nested setState(); How to make object generic? (too many different fields/keys of states)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have nested state which is needed to set its state by key's value.

```
state = {
    income_source: {
        type: 'text', label_name: 'Income Source', value: '', helper: 'dropdown',
    },
    employment_status: {
        type: 'text', label_name: 'Employment Status', value: '', helper: 'dropdown',
    },

...
```

I'm getting huge list from `get_financial_assessment` object and the code becomes messy when I tried to `setState` in componentDidMount().

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let { get_financial_assessment } = await DAO.getFinancialAssessment()
    if( get_financial_assessment ) {
        const {
            account_turnover,
            cfd_score,
            education_level,
            employment_industry,
            employment_status,
            estimated_worth,
            financial_information_score,
            income_source,
            net_income,
            occupation,
            source_of_wealth,
            total_score,
            trading_score,
        } = get_financial_assessment;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            anticipated_account_turnover: {...prevState.anticipated_account_turnover, value: account_turnover},
            occupation: {...prevState.occupation, value: cfd_score},
            level_of_education: {...prevState.level_of_education, value: education_level},
            source_of_wealth: {...prevState.source_of_wealth, value: employment_industry},
            net_annual_income: {...prevState.net_annual_income, value: employment_status},
            estimated_net_worth: {...prevState.estimated_net_worth, value: estimated_worth},
            source_of_wealth: {...prevState.source_of_wealth, value: financial_information_score},
        }));
    } else {
        console.log('nope');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
1) One possible approach might be,,, once we get the data, we can make an object and setState the object to the state. -> It might be the best possible answer? 
2) Any other approach???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to iteratively map them to the new object with updated `value`.

It seems like you are keeping some static data that will not be updated via API in the state though, so a better approach might be to keep them in a separate variable:

```
const metaData = {
  income_source: {
    type: 'text', label_name: 'Income Source', helper: 'dropdown' // no `value` here
  },
  ...
}
```

Then your state will just need to contain the actual dynamic data:

```
state = {
  income_source: '',
  employment_status: ''
  ...
}
```

And updating it will simply be:

```
this.setState(get_financial_assessment);
```

You can also use object destructuring to avoid setting unwanted states:

```
const { trading_score, unwantedProperty, ...imptData } = get_financial_assessment;
this.setState(imptData);
```

If you want to have a simpler initial state, you can also do this:

```
state = {
  data: {}
}
....
this.setState({ data: get_financial_assessment })
...
// in `render`, provide default value if property is not set
{this.state.data.income_source || ''}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...!! But I can't store meta_data.. Here is my actual code: https://github.com/ruskakimov/binary-static/blob/settings_with_sidebar/src/javascript/app_2/pages/settings/sections/financial_assessment.jsx

Comment: I'm trying to carefully read through your answer but it's not clear to me how I can refactor my code... could you look up my code in link??